# How can I update a column based on a calculation of other columns in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to give each player a rank / position based on the values of other columns, 1 being the best position. Each prize or penalty is worth a different amount. Can this be done in SQL and how would I go about putting this into a query? Here is the ratio that i had in mind:

((gold * 8) + (silver * 4) + (bronze * 2)) - ((disq * 4) + penalty) = points

The 'points' are insignificant, ideally I would be able to update the query if the ratio changes.

| id | name | gold | silver | bronze | disq | penalty | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ben | 1 | 4 | 8 |  | 5 |  |
| 2 | kim | 4 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 |  |
| 3 | sarah | 2 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 4 | matt |  | 10 | 2 | 1 | 3 |  |
| 5 | jane | 2 | 3 | 5 |  | 1 |  |

Comment: `UPDATE xxx SET rank = ((gold * 8) + (silver * 4) + (bronze * 2)) - ((disq * 4) + penalty)`

Comment: What value matches empty cells in shown table? NULL?

Comment: Yes there are NULL values in the table.

Comment: Don't store values calculated from other columns, it will lead to data inconsistency sooner or later. Create a view instead, or have a computed column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to give each player a rank / position based on the values
> of other columns, 1 being the best position

You could use the rank window function as follow:

```
select id, 
        rnk as `rank`, 
        rank()over( order by rnk desc) as new_rank
from ( select id,
              name,
              ((coalesce(gold,0) * 8) + (coalesce(silver,0) * 4) + (coalesce(bronze,0) * 2)) - ((coalesce(disq,0) * 4) + coalesce(penalty,0)) as rnk
       from test 
     ) as tbl;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/3FiKkmVA

*Note* , you need to use coalesce for the null values

Or you could update your table with the rank

```
update test t
inner join ( select id, 
                    rnk as `rank`, 
                    rank()over( order by rnk desc) as new_rank
             from ( select id,
                           name,
                           ((coalesce(gold,0) * 8) + (coalesce(silver,0) * 4) + (coalesce(bronze,0) * 2)) - ((coalesce(disq,0) * 4) + coalesce(penalty,0)) as rnk
                    from test 
                   ) as tbl
            ) as t2 on t.id=t2.id
set t.`rank`=t2.`new_rank`;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
>  id    name    gold   silver    bronze    disq    penalty rank
>  4     matt    null    10         2        1         3    1
>  5     jane    2        3         5       null       1    1
>  2     kim     4        1         3        1         2    3
>  1     ben     1        4         8       null       5    4
>  3     sarah   2        2         1      null       null  5
> ```

https://dbfiddle.uk/ckwNhf6y

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
with table_1 (ID,Name,gold,silver,bronze,disq,penalty)
as
(
  Select           '1','ben',   '1','4'  ,'8','0','5'
  union all Select '2','kim',   '4','1'  ,'3','1','2'
  union all Select '3','sarah', '2','2'  ,'1','0','0'
  union all Select '4','matt',  '0','10' ,'2','1','3'
  union all Select '5','jane',  '2','3'  ,'5','0','1'
)
Select 
    *,
    RANK() Over (order by x.points desc) as rank
from (
    Select 
        *,
        ((gold * 8) + (silver * 4) + (bronze * 2)) -((disq * 4) + penalty) as points
    from 
        table_1
    ) x
```